# Generating Heighway dragons in Unity C#

Tags: c#, beginner, unity3d

I'm basically looking for a general critique. I'm just starting out and would like to know if I should have done anything differently to make it faster or to make it much more readable. I don't know exactly what happened but I tried it with 14 iterations and it took about 3 minutes to complete. It crashed Unity at 15 and after a restart, completed 15 iterations in half a second. I have a feeling I should just cut the dragon list and add the vertices to the Line Renderer as they're generated but I feel like the way it is now might be easier to read.

Are there any more corners I could be cutting? I lost indentation on the body of the class when I pasted it into the codeblock.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class HeighwayGenerator : MonoBehaviour {
private List<char> direction;
private List<Vector3> dragon;
private Stack <char> stack;
private LineRenderer line;
private float magnitude = 0.0f;

public int iterations = 4;

void Start () {
    direction = new List<char> ();
    stack = new Stack <char> ();
    dragon = new List<Vector3> ();
    line = GetComponent<LineRenderer> ();

    //generate turn list
    generateDirection (iterations);

    //set start direction. Vector3.forward is axis of rotation (0,0,1) 
    transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward, (float)iterations * 45.0f);

    //find segment length of fully iterated list. magnitude of 0th iteration is 10 units from (-5,0) to (5,0)
    magnitude = 10.0f / (Mathf.Pow (Mathf.Sqrt (2), iterations));

    //generate vertices and fill dragon
    generateVertices ();

    //draw line
    line.SetVertexCount (dragon.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < dragon.Count; i++) {
        line.SetPosition(i, dragon[i]);
    }
}

void generateDirection(int _iteration) {
    // Heighway dragon is generated from an initial direction and a list of turns. 
    // This list is generated by: 
    // 1.Pushing previous list into stack.
    // 2.Appending 'R'  
    // 3.Appending reversed and 'negated?' previous list from stack.

    if (direction.Count == 0) {
        direction.Add ('R');
        _iteration -= 1;    
    }
    if (_iteration <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    int _tempCount = direction.Count;
    direction.Add ('R');

    // Reverse and negate previous iteration
    for (int i = 0; i < _tempCount; i++) {
        stack.Push(direction[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < _tempCount; i++) {
        char _tempChar = stack.Pop ();
        if (_tempChar == 'R') {
            direction.Add ('L');
        }
        if (_tempChar == 'L') {
            direction.Add ('R');
        }
    }
    generateDirection (_iteration - 1);
}

void generateVertices() {
    //initial position
    dragon.Add (transform.position);
    //first translation
    transform.position += magnitude * transform.right;
    //second position
    dragon.Add (transform.position);

    // turn/translate/add -- transform.right is forward on XY plane. Vector3.forward is axis of rotation (0,0,1)
    for (int i = 0; i < direction.Count; i++) {
        if(direction[i] == 'R'){
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward, -90.0f);
            transform.position += magnitude * transform.right;
            dragon.Add (transform.position);
        }
        if (direction[i] == 'L') {
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward, 90.0f);
            transform.position += magnitude * transform.right;
            dragon.Add (transform.position);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Some quick coding style remarks:**

- I'm not a fan of [K&R style brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style), and it's a style rarely seen in C# code.
- I like to see access modifiers on everything. Makes things a lot clearer.
- `generateDirection`, `generateVertices` etc: [method names should be in PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx).
- You use the opposite of the usual C# style of having underscores in front of private instance field names, instead you use them for parameters. This is very confusing.
- `'L'` and `'R'` are used repeatedly, so why not convert these into constants?
- Why do you leave a space between your method name and the bracket, e.g. `direction.Add ('R');`?
- `direction` and `dragon` are `List<T>`s, yet their names do not indicate that they are collections. Collection names should be plural, IMHO. I'd even argue this should be the case for `Stack<char> stack`, though that is a borderline case.
- Comment should tell me why, not what. If the method call is `generateVertices();`, I shouldn't need to be informed `//generate vertices and fill dragon` -- unless your method name doesn't tell me everything I need to know.
- `generateDirection` starts with a multi-line comment explaining what the method does. I'd expect such an explanation [in the `<summary>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkxs89c5(v=vs.71).aspx), not in the body of the method.
- `public int iterations = 4;` Why is this public? Why isn't this a `const`? Is it your intention that this amount can be changed by code calling the `HeighwayGenerator`? If so, than it should be a property with a getter/setter, or perhaps you should keep `iterations` private and only allow it to be changed through a method.

---

Concerning this logic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _tempCount; i++) {
    char _tempChar = stack.Pop ();
    if (_tempChar == 'R') {
        direction.Add ('L');
    }
    if (_tempChar == 'L') {
        direction.Add ('R');
    }
}
```

I fail to see how `_tempChar` (a badly named variable, by the way) can be anything other than `'L'` or `'R'`, so the second `if` can just as well be an `else`.

But this code can be even simpler:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _tempCount; i++) {
    direction.Add((stack.Pop() == 'R') ? 'L' : 'R');
}
```

---

The same remark as the previous one can be said of this code:

```
if(direction[i] == 'R'){
    transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward, -90.0f);
    transform.position += magnitude * transform.right;
    dragon.Add (transform.position);
}
if (direction[i] == 'L') {
    transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward, 90.0f);
    transform.position += magnitude * transform.right;
    dragon.Add (transform.position);
}
```

You seem to have copy-pasted three lines which are almost identical for both cases, except for one parameter. If you're doing that, you should extract those lines into a method, or if you feel that's overkill you should simplify your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < direction.Count; i++) {
    transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward, (direction[i] == 'R' ? -90.0f : 90.0f));
    transform.position += magnitude * transform.right;
    dragon.Add (transform.position);
}
```

Comment: I agree about K&R style brackets, but they are the standard Unity uses when generating .cs files, so it's probably better to go with them.

Comment: Oh, and the same goes for method casing. Sadly.

Comment: Also, as for `public int iterations = 4;` that is the standard way of creating a field that can be edited in the Unity inspector. There is another (and better) way though, which is to create a `private int iterations = 4;` and adorn it with a `[SerializeField]` attribute.

Comment: @NickUdell I didn't know all those limitations. That'll teach me to review code for things I don't know about. ;-)

Comment: They're still valid points. I for one ignore Unity's conventions and go with .NET, it feels cleaner. Still petitioning for Unity to serialize properties, too. They currently don't so it all has to be fields.

Answer (score 3):

From your description I assume that this code is working, but reaches
its limits rather quickly due to a lot of recursion.

After looking at
[this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve#.5BUn.5DFolding_the_Dragon)
it looks like you can use a more effective method than evaluating the
rule directly, so I suggest you do that instead.

So, `line.SetVertexCount` can be called directly by calculating the
number of vertices and then you can fill in the vertices directly
without generating a list of directions beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

So, after taking ferada's suggestion and reading the paragraph of the Wiki that I had originally skipped (equal parts arrogance and stupidity), I completely nixed the recursive function along with the lists and stack. It now uses a MUCH simpler and efficient binary operation to determine each turn. I also got rid of the if statements in favor of BCdotWEB's logic suggestion. (I had no idea I could write something like (stack.Pop() == 'R') ? 'L' : 'R'). I'm very new to c# and only have basic knowledge of c++ and java. I also made iterations private and adorned it with [SerializeField] as per Nick Udell's suggestion. The code is now less than a third of the mess that it was. I also realized I have a lot of reading to do concerning naming and indentation conventions. I suspect the LineRenderer of being the cause of the hanging/crashing because it still happens at around 18-19 iterations.

[image: Heighway dragon 16 iterations]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DragonCurve : MonoBehaviour {
    private LineRenderer line;
    private float magnitude = 0.0f;
    private int vertexCount = 0;
    [SerializeField]
    private int iterations = 4;

    void Start () {
        line = GetComponent <LineRenderer> ();
        magnitude = 10.0f / (Mathf.Pow (Mathf.Sqrt (2), (float)iterations));
        vertexCount = (int)Mathf.Pow (2.0f, (float)iterations) + 1;
        line.SetVertexCount (vertexCount);
        transform.Rotate (transform.forward, (float)(iterations) * 45.0f);

        line.SetPosition (0, transform.position);
        transform.position += magnitude * transform.right;
        for (int num = 1; num < vertexCount; num++) {
            bool turn = (((num & -num) << 1) & num) != 0;
            line.SetPosition (num, transform.position);
            transform.Rotate (transform.forward, ((turn == false ? -90.0f : 90.0f)));
            transform.position += magnitude * transform.right;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI If you're looking for documentation for `(stack.Pop() == 'R') ? 'L' : 'R'`: it's the [Conditional (Ternary) Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4.aspx).